# How to deal with huge output of JSON data in Flask backend

Tags: javascript, python, json, reactjs, flask

I'm just trying to figure out the most efficient way to parse this huge JSON output. When I treat the response like a dictionary, I get an error (shown below). It's being sent to my Flask server from my React front-end in a POST request.

React POST request (I don't think this is where the issue is):

```
send = (data) => {
 // POST
 fetch('http://api', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   body: JSON.stringify({
     "data": data,
   })
 }).then(function (response) {
   return response.text();
 }).then((response) => {
 console.log('POST response: ');
 });
}
```

Flask backend:

```
@app.route('/api/prescription', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def prescription(response={}):

    # POST request
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('prescription POST request')
        response = request.get_json()
        print('response: ',response)
       x = response['data']['tracks'] <- error
       y = response.get('data').get('tracks') <- error
```

Error:

```
x = response['data']['tracks']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

JSON output from "print('response: ',response)":

```
response:  {'data': '{"tracks":[{"album": 
{"album_type":"ALBUM","artists":[{"external_urls":
{"spotify":"https://xyz"},"href":"xyz",
"id":"foijWiojdae","name":"Snail 
Mail","type":"artist","uri":
"spotify:artist:4zxWyxyzI8Fq1jWXJJe"}],
"external_urls":{.... etc (much longer)
```

Answer (score 0):

well the response looks like an object with a string key of data and a string value, but you're indexing into it like the value is an object with a key of tracks and a value of an array.  can you JSON parse the string value of 'data'?

Comment: Yes, calling  x = response['data'] and x = response.get('data') both work.

Comment: so then x in both cases would be a long string, not an object, right? I haven't used python in a while but that's what looks to be the issue.  since x is a string, it throws when you call x['tracks'], it's expecting an integer index.

Comment: You're right! It was expecting an integer index. x[i] returns a single letter. How would I go about parsing this data then?

Comment: that I don't know, I haven't done web stuff with python

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the problem is that `response['data']` is a string. To parse it to an object, you can use [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads).
The result should be something like:

```
import json

@app.route('/api/prescription', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def prescription(response={}):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        response = request.get_json()
        data = json.loads(response['data'])
        tracks = data['tracks']
```